# Answer to question in first chapter of Tanya

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, evil-resha, tanya, maseches-niddah, baal-hatanya

In the first chapter of the Tanya the Alter Rebbe points out a seeming contradiction between a Gemara in Niddah and a Mishna in Avot, concerning the question if one should see oneself as a Rasha or not.

Does anyone know where in the Book  the Baal haTanya answers his question?

Answer (score 6):

Chapter 13 
He explains that one should see them self "כרשע" as having the capacity for sin and should never let their guard down. But not actually as a rasha.